# windows applications that serve video from a local disk to h264 flash viewable through the browser on your local network

Tags: windows, video, flash, gpu, h.264

Are there any windows applications that serve video from a server local disk to h264 flash viewable through the browser on your local network?

I'm thinking that on `machine1`, I'd have a folder with a ton of videos. This program would serve the videos on a website visible at `http://machine1/myvids` and that it would serve them in h264 and do the h264 conversion on the fly using the GPU.

I know it's a lofty set of reqs but I'm wondering if anything like this is out there.

Comment: UPnP servers fulfill the transcoding requisite, but not so much the web interface (none that I've played with yet, anyways). Rolling your own means some scripting/CGI, you can re-use VLC, and... something in there is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I checked, [PlayOn](http://www.playon.tv/playon) supported this.  They do it specifically so you can watch videos on the Wii (via the browser) but if you know how to get to the page, it works from any flash player.  I don't know if it actually uses the GPU, though, and I'm sure you're not going to get the full, original quality / resolution of the videos.  But hey, it's *Flash* for crying out loud -- what did you want? :D